# How to continue working with Logged in Domain User when the Domain Server is down?

Tags: windows-7, windows, domain, windows-server-2012

Windows 2012 and Windows 7 machines:

Some of the users were working in the Domain User Account. While we were working, the domain controller become unavailable and the user accounts got locked. So we were searching for alternatives to get into the Domain User Account to recover the open files/emails?

One alternative that we are aware is that - Login wtih Local Admin and get the documents from Users folder. But the problem is that the opened files are not showing most updated data.

Comment: This unlikely can be solved until the domain server is backup.

Comment: This is entirely dependent on what policies the SysAdmins have in place for when the domain controller is unavailable, which you haven't mentioned. Have you contacted them to see what they are and what you can do to work around them?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to continue to operate without the DC.  When a DC goes down, this does not trigger a 'lock' on client machines.  However, if you lock, disconnect or log out of your session and then attempt to log back in **and** your infrastructure is not configured to allow you to log into your workstation without first communicating with the DC, then you're probably out of luck.